# Convert lower camelCase to PascalCase in c#?

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation, camelcasing, pascalcasing

I need to convert camelcase keys to Pascal key and I got good solution from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46095771/7030060).
But the issue is I don't know how to exclude `.` in conversion.

Please find the below example:

```
var input= "customer.presentAddress.streetName";
```

Expected Output is

```
var output= "Customer.PresentAddress.StreetName";
```

PlayGround : [Please click here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tUBDHb)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0

Comment: @HansPassant Is there any solution using reg expression?

Comment: Split string on '.', set first letter in each value in the array to `toUpper()`. Build string again.

Comment: Okay I will check

Comment: There's an old saying that goes something like. I have a problem. Oh, I know: I'll use a reg ex. Now I have two problems. --- Anyway, basic algorithm outline: foreach(char in string) { if previous was in [A-Za-z], leave alone, otherwise upper case it }.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the @Hans Passant and @JamesS comments, I have rewritten the code :

```
public static string ToPascalCase(this string input)
        {
          return string.Join('.',input.Split('.').Select(x => ConvertToPascalCase(x)));
        }
        private static string ConvertToPascalCase(string input)
        {
            Regex invalidCharsRgx = new Regex(@"[^_a-zA-Z0-9]");
            Regex whiteSpace = new Regex(@"(?<=\s)");
            Regex startsWithLowerCaseChar = new Regex("^[a-z]");
            Regex firstCharFollowedByUpperCasesOnly = new Regex("(?<=[A-Z])[A-Z0-9]+$");
            Regex lowerCaseNextToNumber = new Regex("(?<=[0-9])[a-z]");
            Regex upperCaseInside = new Regex("(?<=[A-Z])[A-Z]+?((?=[A-Z][a-z])|(?=[0-9]))");

            // replace white spaces with undescore, then replace all invalid chars with empty string
            var pascalCase = invalidCharsRgx.Replace(whiteSpace.Replace(input, "_"), string.Empty)
                // split by underscores
                .Split(new char[] { '_' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                // set first letter to uppercase
                .Select(w => startsWithLowerCaseChar.Replace(w, m => m.Value.ToUpper()))
                // replace second and all following upper case letters to lower if there is no next lower (ABC -> Abc)
                .Select(w => firstCharFollowedByUpperCasesOnly.Replace(w, m => m.Value.ToLower()))
                // set upper case the first lower case following a number (Ab9cd -> Ab9Cd)
                .Select(w => lowerCaseNextToNumber.Replace(w, m => m.Value.ToUpper()))
                // lower second and next upper case letters except the last if it follows by any lower (ABcDEf -> AbcDef)
                .Select(w => upperCaseInside.Replace(w, m => m.Value.ToLower()));

            return string.Concat(pascalCase);
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

An idea to use e.g. [`\b\p{Ll}` (demo)](https://regex101.com/r/TceyQV/1) for matching lower word's first letter and [use a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442245/c-sharp-replace-with-callback-function-like-in-as3).

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\b\p{Ll}", match => match.Value.ToUpper());
```

[See this C# demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##ZZDBTsMwDIbveQqrp1Ya2QNUQyC0A9JACDa47BJSq4uUJpHjoKKpz16yFsYQPtn@//j7FR2vtCccxxSNa@HlMzJ2tbic5BZ7ls/YJqto3QfCGI13sRZCWxUjPJFvSXXiKCBXZMVGw4c3DTwo48pqWs/iqZZLuHchcXZSpsizMM9gJnEFhU6RfYckT0h0fNs0J7bMPkR@VB0W9fnx5fldRMh5sc@pg1UagT3QT3tACIoZyWXUNE7Efzl84jnIn1PlZF7ATbF/34fjxg7FAjrF@gCr67mRr8omlFu/CwGprKrflHf537xF@UaGcWMcljPl2zKIYRy/AA) - `\b` is a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) and `\p{Ll}` [matches](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) *lowercase letters*.

Answer (score 3):

I have a code that can solve your problem given that every string is a string array for c# we can do it here:

```
var teste = "customer.presentAddress.streetName".Split(".");

List<string> result = new List<string>();

foreach (var x in teste)
{
    result.Add(string.Concat(x[0].ToString().ToUpper(), x.AsSpan(1)));
}


Console.WriteLine(String.Join(".", result));
```

I converted it to a static method so you can use it wherever you need:

```
public static class ConvertPatternString
{
    public static string ToPascalCase(this string value) =>
    value switch
    {
        null => throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value)),
        "" => throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(value)} cannot be empty", nameof(value)),
        _ => string.Concat(value[0].ToString().ToUpper(), value.AsSpan(1))
    };

    public static string ToPascalCaseWithSeparator(this string value, string separator) =>
    value switch
    {
        null => throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value)),
        "" => throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(value)} cannot be empty", nameof(value)),
        _ => string.Join(separator, value.Split(separator).Select(x => string.Concat(x[0].ToString().ToUpper(), x.AsSpan(1))))
    };
}
```

to use just do:

```
Console.WriteLine("customer.presentAddress.streetName".ToPascalCaseWithSeparator("."));
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also assert that to the left is not a non whitespace char except for a dot, and then match a lowercase char a -z.

Then using `Regex.Replace` with a callback you can change that match to an uppercase char.

```
(?<![^\s.])[a-z]
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!` Negative lookbehind, assert what is directly to the legt is not

  - `[^\s.]` Match a single char other than a whitespace char or dot
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `[a-z]` Match a single char a-z

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WO6Pom/1)